# Configuration with MBUnit

Tags: configuration, mbunit

I want to use MBUnit to write unit tests for my application, however I will require some configuration to be set up.

My understanding is that any App.config files I add to the unit test DLL will not be loaded.  I've looked in the wiki and can't see a way, is there a mechanism for loading my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked into this more by myself, I found [this article](http://www.gallio.org/oldwiki/MbUnit/TestConfigurationFiles.html).

You can do this by creating a config file as you would a regular exe (DllName.dll.config), MBUnit automatically loads this as the appropriate config file.